# Scroll inside vertical navigationbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

i have an example ([JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eg6MZ/1296/)), where i want the content of the nav bar to be scrollable, if it is cut off by the screen size of the browser.
See [Normal Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugmYU.png) and [Small Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O4Vg.png) for current problems.

A requirement is that the left part of the screen (`250px`) is covered by the navigation bar (or any parent) if the screen size is `> 768px`.

I did not achieve any satisfying result so far, therefore i'm aksing for help!

Thanks in advance!

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{
    .sidebar-main.expanded {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .sidebar-main {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-main .navbar {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-main .navbar .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .sidebar-main .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .sidebar-main .navbar-collapse {
        padding: 0px;
        max-height: none;
    }

    .sidebar-main ul {
        float: none;
        &: not {
          display: block;
        }
    }

   .sidebar-main li {
        float: none;
        display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the navbar-header should not scroll together with the content (position should be fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by setting the height manually to a certain PX value in Javascript, although i wanted to avoid this, it seems to me as the only solution.